# change constraints with NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, xcode8

Project's Github [repository](https://github.com/dcollao/coding-autolayout/tree/master/Coding-Autolayout).

So for example, I change this:

```
let orangeViewCenterXConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
  item: orangeView,
  attribute: .centerX,
  relatedBy: .equal,
  toItem: view,
  attribute: .centerX,
  multiplier: 1.0,
  constant: 0.0
)
```

For this:

```
orangeView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
```

How is the proper way to do the same with:

```
let purpleViewBottomSpaceConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
  item: purpleView,
  attribute: .bottom,
  relatedBy: .equal,
  toItem: orangeView,
  attribute: .top,
  multiplier: 1.0,
  constant: -8.0
)
```

I tried with:

```
purpleView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: <#T##NSLayoutAnchor<AnyObject>#>, constant: <#T##CGFloat#>)
```

But I think `purpleView` needs a space between `purpleView` and `orangeView`, so technically `equalTo: orangeView`, `constant: -8.0`, but this is wrong.

I'm not sure of what I'm currently doing, so I'm here to learn.

Comment: Problem solved!, check out the github if you have any question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the `topAnchor`, e.g.:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    purpleView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: orangeView.topAnchor, constant: -8)
])
```

Comment: Thanks!, in xcode8 is:

`purpleView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: orangeView.topAnchor, constant: -8)`

Comment: Yep, in Xcode 8, that's the new syntax. Updated answer accordingly.

Comment: I've another question:
`let purpleViewTopSpaceConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: purpleView,
                                                              attribute: .top,
                                                              relatedBy: .equal,
                                                              toItem: self.topLayoutGuide,
                                                              attribute: .bottom,
                                                              multiplier: 1.0,
                                                              constant: 8.0)`

Comment: Solved:        `purpleView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0)])`

Comment: Correct. You want `topLayoutGuide` if you want that top margin.